# Would it be possible to run GPUs in C++ multithread instead of cuda/opencl?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, opencl

It exist a sw or class that hides the Opencl initial and end part to simplify SW?
I think OpenGL does but I do not know if it is possible to use it only at GPU because efficiency plumbes if you have to download and upload constantly the arrays to GPU.

Running gpus using multithread instead using opencl would be wonderful. Of course new drivers and some HW changes should be performed but the following advantages could be reached:
- Increase performance 12x over opencl (it depends on application, see (1) )
- Increase performance 120x over standard multithread (it depends on application, see (1) )
- Use libraries
- Better debugging
- Exists a lot of SW
- A lot more easy to program
- Better uses of other languages (java, phyton)
- Better access to Hard disk and peripherals

RESPONSE:

- NVIDIA is making GPUs that runs C++:
  [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86seb-iZCnI&feature=youtu.be](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86seb-iZCnI&feature=youtu.be/)
  Running 5120 32bit cores in a single tesla V100 volta architecture card
- NVIDIA is making C++ working on GPUs:
  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0761r2.pdf
- It is adding parallelism to C++:
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vck6kzWjY88&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Are you suggesting that we somehow magically running pure C++ on a GPU would improve performance by tenfold?

Comment: @mathengineer Your post isn't really a question.  But more importantly, I think you should read more about GPU architecture, and why the particulars of OpenCL (or CUDA, or MPI, or even something like Spark or MapReduce) are the way they are.  Parallel computing, beyond the basic case of a multicore CPU, is complicated and somewhat specific to your particular hardware and cluster architecture.

Comment: I read about GPU architecture within a supercomputing european project. To make a multicore CPU can be done using a two levels speed memory access and DMAs. That technology exists. I wrote the post because I think a lot improvements can be done so an open debate must be done. Dozens negative points are welcome if I solve the problem for most the programmers

Comment: @mathengineer StackOverflow the complete wrong platform for this, and because of that you get those down-votes. This platform is for solving problems with your code and with existing libraries on existing hardware. Your _"question"_ is a discussion topic and is something for e.g. a sub reddit, or are a discussion talk.

Comment: >This platform is for solving problems with your code and with existing libraries on existing hardware     Of course, it exists GPU FPGA boards that can work as I said. Working in multithreaded gpus allows using that existing libraries on GPUs

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR : Is it possible ? Maybe. Is it a good idea ? No, because (spoiler) a **GPU is not a CPU**.

A CPU can do everything, all operations your computer can do even graphical operation.

A GPU is a specialized type of microprocessor, optimized for graphical task which needs a lot of simple parallel "dumb" operation. A GPU can only perform a fraction of the many operations a CPU does (but it does it very well).

C++ is an efficient language because compilers are made to optimize it (in assembly form) for your CPU. On a GPU, you do not have the same set of instruction available. It means you'll have to replace complex instructions by multiple simpler ones (assuming it is possible), so an action which required 1 instruction, would take 2...4...10... instructions now ! And do not forget the GPU clock is generally slower than the CPU clock. I do not see where the optimization is.

Also, I'm really curious to know where you find the values (12x, 120x, etc...) you're presenting in your question.

Comment: It is less about the different instructions set. Even if they would have the same amount of instructions as a certain CPU Architectur, you won't get the same performance. Simply said, a CPU is designed to work with code flow that is much less predictable, memory allocations that can change greatly at any time, many context switches, ... . GPUs on the other hand run one code chunk at a time and and the memory allocation wont change (or only in a very limited way) while that chunk is executed. Those limitations the GPU needs to apply to memory allocation and code flow will hurt "dynamic" code.

Comment: @t.niese, Thank you for this information about memory, I didn't thought about it  :)

Comment: you are not be able to delete any comment of another person, as long as you don't have access to that account. So the comment was delete by the one owning the account mathengineer.

Comment: >GPUs on the other hand run one code chunk at a time and and the memory allocation wont change. There are processors that have 4 high speed cores and 4 slower, so it would be possible multithread in then following way: using a lot of parallel simple processors to make math operations     and only one or two designed to use more complex operations. In graphical programming and simulator it is needed a lot of alus in parallel but very few processing needs to make complex operations. GPU manages math lib and also a simple C, it should be easy add classes.

Comment: @mathengineer It does not really make a difference if it is a SoC/Integrated-GPU or a dedicated GPU. There is already unified memory and other high peromant resource sharing. There is also _"no"_ problem to add C++ (or any other language) using SPIR for OpenCL or Vulkan, like CUDA does. And the lack of libraries is not a limitation of the hardware. Anyhow the problem is still the same, you need to design the code in a way that it is optimal for the given architecture, no matter if it is SoC or dedicated. You descripe the existing system in a different way, but the problems are still the same.

Comment: My idea is not to describe the existing HW but to ask for a new HW/SW architecture to incorporate hundred kernels to actual CPU instead of using GPUs through opencl (or cuda) that is about to reach the development limit. Library lack is a real big limitation.